# How to calculate the steps_per_epoch from TFRecordDataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

When training a `tensorflow model` with:

```
model.fit(..., steps_per_epoch=10000, ....)
```

I want to calculate the `steps_per_epoch` from the provided dataset:

```
dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset([filenames])
dataset = dataset.repeat(1)
dataset = dataset.batch(512)

total = 0
for i in dataset:
    total += 1

print("Total is {}".format(total))
```

The output is:

```
Total is 393
```

Is the `steps_per_epoch` equal to `393`?

or

`steps_per_epoch` = `393 / 512` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameter steps_per_epoch is part of model training only when we use a large size dataset. `steps_per_epoch` determines the batches to train in a single dataset to improve the accuracy of the model.

`steps_per_epoch` depends on the `batch_size` and the `training_set` size

```
batch_size=50
trainingsize = 30000 

def calculate_spe(y, batch_size):
  return int(math.ceil((1. * y) / batch_size)) 

stepsPerEpoch = calculate_spe(trainingsize, batch_size)
```

after calculating steps per epochs you can use it as:

```
model.fit(..., steps_per_epoch = stepsPerEpoch , ....)
```

Comment: Thank you. I still get confused with: Is the trainingsize = total =  len( tf.data.TFRecordDataset ) = 393? Or is the trainingsize = total * bach_size =  len( tf.data.TFRecordDataset ) * bach_size = 393 * 512?

Comment: trainingsize is the dataset length over which the model is being trained.